# Could a custom EditorTemplate invoke default EditorTemplate for the same model inside it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Could a custom EditorTemplate invoke default EditorTemplate for the same model inside it? Same applies to DisplayTemplates as well. Here is a simplified example. While the LabelForModel is rendered, neither DisplayForModel or EditorForModel is rendered.

View

```
<div class="highlight1">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NullableProp, "NullableIntType1View")
</div>
<div class="highlight2">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NullableProp, "NullableIntType1View")
</div>
<div class="highlight1">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NullableProp, "NullableIntType2View")
</div>
<div class="highlight2">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NullableProp, "NullableIntType2View")
</div>
```

Shared/DisplayTemplates/NullableIntType1.cshtml

```
@model System.Int32?

This is display for NullableIntType1
<hr />  --> @Html.EditorForModel()  <--
<hr />  --> @Html.DisplayForModel() <--
<hr />  --> @Html.LabelForModel()   <--
```

Shared/EditorTemplates/NullableIntType1.cshtml

```
@model System.Int32?

This is editor for NullableIntType1
<hr />  --> @Html.EditorForModel()  <--
<hr />  --> @Html.DisplayForModel() <--
<hr />  --> @Html.LabelForModel()   <--
```

Shared/DisplayTemplates/NullableIntType2.cshtml

```
@model System.Int32?

This is display for NullableIntType2
<hr />  --> @Html.EditorForModel()  <--
<hr />  --> @Html.DisplayForModel() <--
<hr />  --> @Html.LabelForModel()   <--
```

Shared/EditorTemplates/NullableIntType2.cshtml

```
@model System.Int32?

This is editor for NullableIntType2
<hr />  --> @Html.EditorForModel()  <--
<hr />  --> @Html.DisplayForModel() <--
<hr />  --> @Html.LabelForModel()   <--
```